# WebRequest in Spring throws vulnerability in sonar qube

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sonarqube

In my code i am implementing ResponseEntityExceptionHandle to handle exceptions.

When i override handleMissingServletRequestParameter method. Sonar qube is complaining vulnerability issue for variable WebRequest request.

Method Definition.

```
 @Override
 protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(
  final MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, final HttpHeaders 
 headers,
  final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {

final String error = ex.getParameterName() + " parameter is missing";
final ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse =
    new ExceptionResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), error);
return constructResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, headers, request, ex);
```

}

Sonar qube error is shown at the last return statement as given below.

```
[request] not sanitized with standard sanitization methods: normalize, 
encode [Note: As applicable, validate class member variables of type String, 
StringBuffer, CharSequence]
```

How to fix the issue.